# Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(442,5): error : Two assets found targeting the same path with incompatible asset kinds

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, .net-6.0

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(442,5):
> error : Two assets found targeting the same path with incompatible
> asset kinds: [D:\Migration\XXXXXX\XXXX.App\XXXX.csproj] C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(442,5):
> error : ‘D:\Migration\XXXXXX\XXXX.App\wwwroot\assets\images\AAA.png’
> with kind ‘All’ [X:\Migration\XXXXXX\XXXX.App\XXXX.csproj] C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(442,5):
> error : ‘X:\Migration\XXXXXX\XXXX.App\wwwroot\assets\images\AAA.png’
> with kind ‘All’ [D:\Migration\XXXXXX\XXXX.App\XXXX.csproj] C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(442,5):
> error : for path ‘assets/images/Cancel.png’
> [D:\Migration\XXXXXX\XXXX.App\XXXX.csproj] 0 Warning(s) 1 Error(s)

Error occurs while building the Solution. Not sure why this error is happening in .NET 6, the same copy of wwwroot folder content to output directory works fine in .Netcore3.1. But giving error in .Net 6.

Did initial research on any other alterative for this problem. It only builds if content of wwwroot folder are deleted each time in the project directory location. hence works fine on the first time of clean workspace.

Background: basically need to copy the icons and images used in client to wwwroot folder and also copying this to output directory using

Sample mini project is in git https://github.com/Shruthi1984/StaticWebAssestscopyissue .

Comment: Does not seem to be a lot of documentation on this error, the way my project is setup I want to keep the files in both project, did you find a way to work around this error?

Comment: same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673639/visual-studio-2022-v-17-6-5-link-installed-nuget-package-css-file-in-layout)...Visual Studio 2022 - v.17.6.5

Answer (score 7):

Similar error propped up in our project after upgrading to `net6.0`

Project had a `.nuget` package reference to said static asset(i.e *bootstrap*), and also files under `wwwroot` folder. The duplication made the project to throw error. We removed the reference to package. And that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, while adding some files, Rider created a bunch of entries in `.csproj` like

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="wwwroot\[...]" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="wwwroot\[...]" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

They are useless - `wwwroot\**` is already included by default - and removing them fixed the `Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets` build errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating from .net5.0 to .net6.0. The error happened because I had this command in the project file:

```
<Content Include="$(ProjectDir)\wwwroot\**\*.*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
```

After removing it I was finally able to build the project, because in .NET 6 the copying is automatically done and it will try to copy the files twice with this command

Comment: Thats not really a solution. I want to keep this while still compiling

Comment: We encountered the same problem. Looks like in .net 6 it already copies stuff to the output folder even without that extra statement in the project file. So that extra statement may copy it for the second time causing the error?

Comment: @JohantHart you are correct

Answer (score 0):

you just remove or uninstall bootstrap packages from your project it be solved