# Visual Studio 2022 - v.17.6.5 - link installed nuget package css file in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: .net-6.0, nuget-package, visual-studio-2022

I created a new `.net 6.0 MVC Web project` and removed the preinstalled `bootstrap` from `wwwroot/lib` because I wanted to add it with `NuGet Package Manager`. After installing the package, files are shown as a reference in my `wwwroot`, and when I try to link them from code browser gives `not found error` cause they don't actually exists in my project.

Now I'm trying this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" />` but as I said is not working. The only solution I've got is to copy those file from `C\..nuget\packages` to my `wwwroot` but I've read that this reference is actually an intended behaviour from Microsoft, so it should be a way to use those referenced files but I can't seem to find it.

How should I reference those files in my code to be able to use them?

[image]

Also after copying files to project and running the project I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Two assets found targeting the same path with incompatible asset kinds:
> 'C:\Users....nuget\packages\bootstrap\5.3.0\contentFiles\any\any\wwwroot\css\bootstrap-grid.css' with kind 'All'
> '...\Tickets\Tickets\wwwroot\css\bootstrap-grid.css' with kind 'All'
> for path 'css/bootstrap-grid.css'   Tickets C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets    419

I need to remove the package from manager to overcome this error...

Comment: That's kind of expected..The contents of nuget files are copied to the destination, either automatically (dll files) or manually (most other files). They're never referenced directly in the package folder.

Comment: so it shouldn't be like that...

Comment: It's a bit uncommon to use this for html and css, but yes, it should be like that. You should copy the files from your package to your destination/project folder, not reference it there.

Comment: Can I suggest you use the Client Side library instead of the NuGet package? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353885/how-to-install-and-use-the-latest-bootstrap-in-an-mvc5-project